# Can't stop seleniumwire defaulting to https

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I'm trying to use seleniumwire with the chrome webdriver to automate a task that is tedious and it seems like it's redirecting from my input of `http://somesite.com:port/` to `https://somesite.com:port/`. When the browser opens, it gives me a 502 error, but I can then manually remove/restore to http:// and it works.

I'm revisiting old code that I hadn't finished working on but did work just fine in the past and it's only now started failing with this error.

Any ideas as to how to force the http to stick?

Comment: It might not be linked to selenium, but a chrome thing. But that wouldn't explain why typing http manually instead of https wouldn't behave the same way. I tried converting to Firefox and it now connects, but I get encoding errors on returned request data.